# How to output RVM needed download URLs

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to install RVM in my workstation.
But in my work's network, the internet is reached via an proxy. This proxy eventually blocks some URLs based in a internal security policy.

I shall to do a request to network administrators about URLs that is being blocked so that they can unblock them for a group of workstations.
This is very important because the policy need to be constantly updated.

What I need is to know which URL the installation is trying to download and that are being blocked.

When I try to install RVM it try to download the archives. The blocked ones arrives corrupted in my computer. I can see messages in the output complaining checksum errors.

e.g.

```
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p0, this may take a while depending on your connection...

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:--     0
100  3198  100  3198    0     0    532      0  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--   532

Downloaded archive checksum did not match, archive was removed!
If you wish to continue with not matching download add '--verify-downloads 2' after the command.

There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

How can I see the URLs beings downloaded in the RVM install? Probably I'll need this for the gems bundler too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure this might help: https://rvm.io/workflow/proxy/, as I undertand it, once you install RVM that way, it will use that proxy from there on.

Comment: Additionally, most versions are fetch from github: `https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/`. You can take a look at the installer: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/binscripts/rvm-installer

Comment: The setup of the proxy isn't the problem. Proxy is already configured. What I need is to see what is passing through the proxy.

Comment: In such case, then `https://github.com` domain should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run:

```
rvm get head              # make sure you use latest rvm code
rvm cleanup archives      # clean up all downloaded files so far 
rvm install 2.0.0 --debug # install with debug - it will show the downloaded urls
```

Comment: As I'm installing, rvm command isn't configured yet. I have located the command in the path /usr/local/rvm and have run. The output generated is showing all URLs now! Seems like it solved the problem...

Comment: What is the difference? Why running these commands instead of the command of RVM installation show the URLs?

Comment: The binaries of ruby language is not coming from Github. They are coming from http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub

Answer (score 0):

It gives a **lot** of output, but if you install with the `--debug --trace` switches then you see *everything* that RVM is doing, including the URLs that it requests:

```
$ rvm install 2.0.0 --debug --trace
# ...
# a whole boatload of output
# such as...
+++ 1365712695.744278786 /scripts/functions/utility : __rvm_ruby_package_file()  569 > rvm_ruby_package_file=/ruby-2.0.0-rc2.tar.bz2
+++ 1365712695.856579187 /scripts/functions/utility : __rvm_calculate_remote_file()  583 > __remote_file=https://rvm.io/binaries/ubuntu/12.10/i386/ruby-2.0.0-rc2.tar.bz2
+++ 1365712695.948514158 /scripts/functions/utility : __rvm_remote_server_path_single()  592 > [[ -z https://rvm.io/binaries/ubuntu/12.10/i386/ruby-2.0.0-rc2.tar.bz2 ]]
+++ 1365712696.053688755 /scripts/functions/utility : __rvm_remote_server_path_single()  597 > file_exists_at_url https://rvm.io/binaries/ubuntu/12.10/i386/ruby-2.0.0-rc2.tar.bz2
+++ 1365712696.171561756 /scripts/functions/utility : file_exists_at_url()  714 > [[ -n https://rvm.io/binaries/ubuntu/12.10/i386/ruby-2.0.0-rc2.tar.bz2 ]]
+++ 1365712696.266908604 /scripts/functions/utility : file_exists_at_url()  716 > unset curl
+++ 1365712696.482119274 /scripts/functions/utility : file_exists_at_url()  717 > curl -slkL --max-time 3 --head https://rvm.io/binaries/ubuntu/12.10/i386/ruby-2.0.0-rc2.tar.bz2
+++ 1365712696.512878217 /scripts/functions/utility : file_exists_at_url()  718 > GREP_OPTIONS=
+++ 1365712696.732889205 /scripts/functions/utility : file_exists_at_url()  718 > grep -E 'HTTP/[0-9\.]+ 200 OK'
```

Comment: It seems that the last download made in the installation isn't appearing in the output even with these flags... It's trying to download ruby source and I'm not seeing where it come from. Maybe it's coming from Github.

Comment: @VictorDolirio unless it's installing a binary, it's very likely to be coming from Github. As you can see from the snippet in my answer, binaries are downloaded from http://rvm.io.